# Is It Possible to Restore Accidentally Deleted Widgets?

Tags: widgets, mysql, backup, customization

I accidentally deleted the widgets without dragging it to the inactive widgets section.

I have a backup of all the files and the database but i have changed many things on the site other than the widgets.

Can I only restore the widgets?

Answer (score 2):

You have to search the `wp_options` database table for `option_name`'s that contains `widget`.

[image: searching for widgets in wp_options table]

That search results in:

[image: search result of the query]

Using the values of your backups, you'll then proceed to restore the `option_value` of the missing widgets. **And also** the value of the option of `sidebars_widgets`.

Goes without saying that backing up before doing this modifications is **essential**.

Comment: I Inserted the option_value with a new name.the widget is not showing up in the dashboard.please help

Comment: What do you mean, new name?

Answer (score 0):

Due to my impatience and lack of confidence in Hostgator's willingness to assist me with this issue, I have found a possible solution if you are comfortable looking at source code. I recommend looking up the site you wish to recover the widgets from [The WayBackMachine](http://web.archive.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Accidently deleted very essential widgets (wifi and battery) 
so created a new user and then copied its configuration to the older one, 
and IT WORKED!